# We are created workflows in sharepoint designer 2013.when i try to run the workflows it not show the assigned page? it redirect to list

Tags: designer-workflow

The workflow will be stated, but when I click on stated it redirect to list. It doesn't show the whom I am assigned required data. Can you please give the answer?

Comment: could u add an screenshot of your WF